# how to add new column of data from user created function and correlate to different columns

Tags: r

I have a function

```
POMP <- function(N, S, A) {
(N-S)/(A-S)
}
```

and I use it to create what is called a POMP score. I then use

```
POMP(Flanker_Nor_Incongruent.RT, Flanker_Spe_Incongruent.RT, Flanker_Acc_Incongruent.RT)
```

to get the POMP scores for each row (participant in my study). I want to input all these scores into the corresponding row in a new column. How do I do that? Also, how then do I correlate these scores to another column in the same data frame?

My data looks like this

```
 Flanker_Nor_Incongruent.RT Flanker_Spe_Incongruent.RT Flanker_Acc_Incongruent.RT
1           400                     200                           500        
2           300                     250                           400
3           500                     400                           600
4           200                     150                           400
```

I want

```
 Flanker_Nor_Incongruent.RT Flanker_Spe_Incongruent.RT Flanker_Acc_Incongruent.RT POMP Score
1           400                     200                           500                  2/3 
2           300                     200                           400                  1/2                  
3           500                     400                           600                  1/2
4           200                     100                           400                  1/3
```

Comment: `Flanker_Nor_Incongruent$POMP_SCORE <-  POMP(Flanker_Nor_Incongruent.RT, Flanker_Spe_Incongruent.RT, Flanker_Acc_Incongruent.RT)`

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you give a sample of your data set but say it looks like this:

```
letters
   N  S  A
1 N1 S1 A1
2 N2 S2 A2
3 N3 S3 A3
```

then just do:

```
sapply(letters$N,POMP,letters$S,letters$A)
```

note that you pass the other parameters of the function to sapply after the function.